# How to replace all recurrences of something in a list with something else

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry if the title is a bit vague, but I would like to go through a list and replace all occurrences of `'\\'` with `'/'`. Here's an example:

```
list = ['C:/dir\\file.txt', 'C:/dir\\example.zip', 'C:/dir\\example2.zip']
```

I'd like to filter out the `'\\'` in all of the individual paths with `'/'` for readability reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [str.replace](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes#str.replace):

```
>>> 'C:/dir\\file.txt'.replace('\\', '/')
'C:/dir/file.txt'
```

Applying `str.replace` to all paths, you get replaced paths.

```
>>> paths = list = ['C:/dir\\file.txt', 'C:/dir\\example.zip', 'C:/dir\\example2.zip']
>>> paths = [path.replace('\\', '/') for path in paths]
>>> paths
['C:/dir/file.txt', 'C:/dir/example.zip', 'C:/dir/example2.zip']
```

Comment: fairly sure str.replace is depreciated in python-3 (it's not even in the manual for 3.3)

Comment: @OliverMatthews, You are wrong. http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes#str.replace

Comment: Ah, I see. the string module's replace function was depreciated. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You should be handling paths using `os.path` rather than by hand, but since you must, here you go:

```
[re.sub("\\\\",'/',x) for x in list]
```